# Problemas ao tentar recuperar dados do firebase Realtime database

Tags: angular, ionic, firebase, typescript, firebase-database

Estou fazendo meu TCC utilizando Ionic 4 e o firebase authentication e o Realtime Database, faz alguns dias que acabei travando quando tento recuperar somente um usuário do banco, quando os dados do usuário são salvos, a ID utilizada e a mesma do auth, quando tentei trazer todos os usuários salvos no banco funcionou sem problemas, mas ao tentar trazer somente 1 usuário (o usuário que esta logado) não esta funcionando. O erro que recebo e o seguinte

> Type 'Observable>>' is missing the following properties from type 'Usuario': nome, curso, idade, telefone, and 2 more.ts(2740)

Esses são os códigos que estou usando

Esse e o service

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
 import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';



 export interface Usuario {
  nome : string;
  curso: string;
  idade : number;
  telefone : number;
  sexo: string;
  tipo: string;
 }


 @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class UsuarioServiceService {


  constructor(private banco : AngularFireDatabase, private authCtrl : 
AngularFireAuth) {
 }
}
```

Esse e meu arquivo TypeScript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Usuario } from '../usuario-service.service';
import  'rxjs/add/operator/take';



@Component({
 selector: 'app-usuario-perfil',
 templateUrl: './usuario-perfil.page.html',
 styleUrls: ['./usuario-perfil.page.scss'],
})

export class UsuarioPerfilPage implements OnInit {

  usuario : Usuario = {
    nome: '',
    curso: '',
    idade : null,
    telefone : null,
    sexo: '',
    tipo: '',
  }

  constructor( private banco : AngularFireDatabase, private authCtrl : 
  AngularFireAuth) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  this.authCtrl.authState.take(1).subscribe(data  =>  {
    if(data && data.email && data.uid){
      this.usuario = this.banco.object<Usuario> 
    (`/usuarios/${data.uid}`).snapshotChanges();
      console.log(data.email)
    }
  else{
    console.log('erro');
   }
  });

 }
}
```

O erro acontece quando tento colocar os dados que pego do banco para a variável de usuário para que depois possa utilizar a mesma no HTML para mostrar os dados.

Ja tentei cria um Observable, um AngularFireObject e inúmeras outras soluções que vi por ai mas nada deu certo, alguém sabe oque posso fazer?

Comment: Inclua o código ao invés de capturas da tela

Answer (score 0):

experimenta assim:

```
this.banco.database.ref('/usuarios').orderByKey().equalTo(uid)
  .once('value', (snap) => {
    if (snap.val()) {
      console.log(snap.val()[0]);
    } else {
      console.log('erro');
    }
  })
```

como é uma lista estou pegando o registro 0 mas vc poderia iterar com a classe objeto ex:

```
const snap  = snap.val();
Object.keys(snap).foreach( key => {
    console.log(snap[key]);
})
```

se tiver algum errinho me perdoa porque digitei direto aqui o codigo e não teste.

abraço